# TagCloud for Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-to-winforms

are there any ?

found this prev question
[Tag cloud control for WinForms .NET 2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278342/tag-cloud-control-for-winforms-net-2-0)
but that's 2 yrs old so hoping there may have been progress since

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only thing close I could find:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/TagCloud.aspx